# How can i apply different CSS styles to 2 different element with same class name?

Tags: css, sass

I'm working on a website i have just one long page and i split it to 5 different section. In every section i have some same figure with different size. I created different folders, jsx files and scss files for each section. For the same figures i used same class names but if i don't change specific properties, it takes from the other section. Is there any way to block that ?

jsx file

```
import './MoreFeatures.scss'

const MoreFeatures = () => {
return (
    <div className="MoreFeature">
        <div className="SectionTitle">
            <div className="Subtext">
                <div className="Line"></div>
                <p>More Features</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

scss file

```
.SectionTitle{
position: absolute;
width: 748px;
height: 219px;
left: 152px;
top: 2675px;
background: rebeccapurple;

.Subtext{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    right: 10.59%;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 90.41%;
    background: orangered;
```

In there i didn't put width properties but when i run there is this.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the file also has an inline `<style>` element that is adding the width and height properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in the console is how the final element is styled. CSS is referred to as **cascading** as child objects inherit their parents objects unless explicitly stated.

Try moving your 'Subtext' element out, or setting it's width/height values to `auto` or `100%`

Comment: So if want to use same class names i have to set width/height values, right ? Or i have to change the class name.

Comment: @hegonen you aren't using the same class name more than once in the supplied code?
To give an element multiple classes,  put a space between them on the same element, E.G `<div className="Subtext Line">`

Answer (score 0):

the same class name you can't apply but using different IDs, the class you can apply CSS to each element.

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` properties are coming from elsewhere. You have an inline `<style>` element that is adding them.

```html
<style>
    .Subtext {
        position: absolute;
        width: 176px;
        height: 21px;
        left: 736px;
        top: 2002px;
    }
</style>
```

You can tell in the image that you provided that the source isn't the SCSS file.

[image]